# How To Have An Element Show Based On Parent Class In Tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css

I have setup a group hover class in tailwind so when an li is hovered a child span shows, i also add an "active" class to the li when needed. What i need is when the active class is present on the li the child span is also visible. Could someone point me at how to do that as i'm a bit stuck.

The below works fine, just not sure how to add the above.

```
variants: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: ['hover', 'focus'],
            borderWidth: ['hover', 'focus'],
            display: ['group-hover']
        },
    },
```

Comment: please provide your code ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle between visible and invisible elements by using display utilities. So in order to hide an element, give it the class `hidden`, then to display it, add a group-hover prefix to `block`, `flex`, `grid`, etc...

```
<ul class='group'>
  <li class='hidden group-hover:block'> </li>
  <li class='hidden group-hover:block'> </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

you can do like this

```
 <div class="bg-green-200 group">
  <button class="text-gray-700 font-semibold py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center">
    <span class="mr-1">Dropdown</span>
    <svg class="fill-current h-4 w-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
      <path d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <ul class="group-hover:block hidden text-gray-700 pt-1 bg-green-50">
    <li class=""><a class="py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap" href="#">One</a></li>
    <li class=""><a class="py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap" href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li class=""><a class="py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap" href="#">Three is the magic number</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question at all.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet could you take a look first
https://play.tailwindcss.com/Z2XwwP394v

Comment: The question is about how to show a child element _when the parent element has a specific class_ (in this case `active`). Your answer shows how to show an element when you hover over the parent element, which is the part that’s already working in the question.